# PHP Pagination Controls Style

Tags: php, css

On pagination controls how do I get the active class to work.
The CSS style for a:active is not showing up (everything else seems fine on the controls).

**Pagination Code:**

```
//start pagination
//Get the total count of rows.
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

//Here we have the total row count
$rows = $row[0];

//Number of results to show per page
$page_rows = 21;

//This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

//This makes sure last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
//establish the $pagenum variable
$pagenum = 1;

//Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}

//This makes sure the page number isn't below 1 or more than our $last page
if($pagenum < 1){
    $pagenum = 1;
} else if($pagenum > $last) {
    $pagenum = $last;
}
//This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum
$limit = 'LIMIT ' . ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

//This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying the limit variable
$sql = "SELECT id, image, fname, surname, address FROM users ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

//This shows the user what page they are on and the total number of pages
$textline1 = "<b>$rows</b> Users";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";

//$paginationCrls variable
$paginationCtrls = ' ';

//if there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /*First we check if we are on page one.  If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing.  If we aren't then we generate links to the first page and to the previous page.*/

    if($pagenum > 1){
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?pn=' .$previous. '">&#171; Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        //Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0) {                
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?pn=' . $i .'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;';
            }
        }
    }
//Render the target page number, but without it being a link
$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
//Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
    $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;';
    if($i >= $pagenum+4){
        break;
    }
}
//This adds the same as above only checking if if we are on the last page and then generating Next
if($pagenum != $last){
    $next = $pagenum + 1;
    $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next &#187;</a> ';
}
}
//Finish Pagination
```

**CSS Code:**

```
div#pagination_controls a:active{
    border: 1px solid #C00;
    background-color: #C00;
    color: #3f3f3f;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your active page doesn't render as a link. Try changing these lines:

```
//Render the target page number, but without it being a link
$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
```

to

```
//Render the target page number, but without it being a link
$paginationCtrls .= '<span class="active">'.$pagenum.'</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;';
```

and

```
div#pagination_controls a:active
{
    border: 1px solid #C00;
    background-color: #C00;
    color: #3f3f3f;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
}
```

to

```
div#pagination_controls span.active
{
    border: 1px solid #C00;
    background-color: #C00;
    color: #3f3f3f;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Cool, it works, thanks for helping Taha, spent a while looking at it.